How do I get all sheet names in an Excel file using Polars?
We know how to read Excel file using Polars:
import polars as pl
df = pl.read_excel()

In pandas we have the capability to get all sheet names. Do we have such functionality in Polars?
xl = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')

# Get sheet names
sheet_names = xl.sheet_names


It does not look like it exists in the current API. Polars is using fastexcel, which you could use directly: http://fastexcel.toucantoco.dev/fastexcel.html#ExcelReader.sheet_names - (it also has a .to_polars() method)

Please see the polars source code. The offical method is below:
import fastexcel
parser = fastexcel.read_excel(source, **engine_options)
sheets = [{"index": i + 1, "name": nm} for i, nm in enumerate(parser.sheet_names)]

